# Minify files before FTP upload

Tags: html, cpanel, minify

Most of my HTML, JavaScript and CSS files are written with a lot of spaces and comments that just add to the bulk. To keep editing simple, I prefer to have them this way, however, it's not so good on my website. Is there an easy way to minify these files before uploading to my server, or perhaps use cPanel to minify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for grunt.js ( http://gruntjs.com/ ), or something similar, like gulp.js.

They're just task-runners, build-automaters, etc. I know grunt already has modules available that do minification/concatenation/other space saving things, and you can probably make your own module to FTP them to your server.

You could also achieve the functionality you're looking for by just writing a simple BASH script.